# account local functions as valid while making a debugger in lua

Tags: debugging, lua

-- Exercise 25.8 -- One problem with the sandbox in Figure 25.6, “Using hooks to bar calls to unauthorized functions” is that sandboxed code cannot call its own functions. How can you correct this problem?

```
local debug = require "debug"

-- Maximum "steps" that can be performed
local steplimit = 1000
local count = 0

-- Counter for steps
-- Set of authorized functions
local validfunc = {}

-- Hook function to check if the called function is authorized
local function hook(event)
    local info
    if event == "call" then
        local info = debug.getinfo(2, "fn")
        if not validfunc[info.func] then
            error("calling bad function: " .. (info.name or "?"))
        end
    end
    count = count + 1
    if count > steplimit then
        error("script uses too much CPU")
    end
    print(string.format('func_name:%s, count:%d', info.name, count))
end

-- Load chunk
local chunkEnv = setmetatable({}, { __index = _G })
local f, errorMsg = loadfile("test_lua_exercise_25_8.lua", "t", chunkEnv)
if not f then
    error("Error loading file: " .. errorMsg)
end

-- Set hook
debug.sethook(hook, "c", 100)

-- Run chunk
f()

-- Capture the functions defined in the chunk and add them to the validfunc table
for k, v in pairs(chunkEnv) do
    if type(v) == "function" then
        validfunc[k] = true
    end
end

-- Set hook to nil to disable it after the execution
debug.sethook()

-- Print the authorized functions
for k, v in pairs(validfunc) do
    print(k, v)
end


test_lua_exercise_25_8.lua
local debug = require "debug"
local count = 0

local function hook (event)
    if event == "call" then
        local info = debug.getinfo(1, "fn")
    end
    
    count = count + 1
    if count > 1000 then
        error("script uses too much CPU")
    end
end

for i = 1, 10 do
    hook('call')    
end
```

I can't make it run. Do anyone have any sugg? Tried many thngs bt i cannot add the running functions into validfunc array very easy. I suppose if i call debug.registry() maybe will be possible bt registry() has to do wth C communication scripts.

Comment: Could you provide Figure 25.6 (or a good description of what it is)?

Comment: @Luatic - It's an exercize from PiL4. `Figure 25.6` is just a code very similar to OP's code.

Comment: Why can't you make it run? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an answer I would find fully satisfactory.

The given implementation gathers functions from `chunkEnv` after loading the file. If the sandboxed code's "own functions" are simply these functions, things are easy. We can detect when new functions are added via a `__newindex` metamethod and immediately add them to the `validfunc` set.

However, the sandboxed code you give as an example doesn't have any functions of this kind -- so we see that this fails for functions that aren't added to the environment table like local functions, or inner functions.

Also, this method is potentially insecure -- the file can whitelist any function simply by adding it to `chunkEnv`. (This already seems like a vulnerability in the existing code if `validfunc` is used later, but adding immediately would allow any read-accessible function to be used inside the `f()` invocation, not just later. But also, it is already allowed for a newly defined function to call a forbidden function as long as that call doesn't happen when the hook is in place (at load time), but maybe that is intended?)

Although a lexical closure is philosophical linked to the environment in which it is instantiated, I don't think we can use this in Lua. The only accessible link of this kind a Lua function has is via upvalues, and functions in the sandbox do not need to have `chunkEnv` as an upvalue -- they may define a new environment, or they might not use `_ENV`. (And in general, there is no guarantee a forbidden function can't end up using `chunkEnv`.)

In terms of book-keeping, then, we are left with debug info. The `source` field of the function debug info record seems like the most appropriate thing to check here. However, depending on the threat model, I would be somewhat worried about the possibility of a forbidden function ending up with a valid `source` -- do the file system and loading model allow two files to end up with the same `source`? Does the attacker have access to `package.loaded`? (With loading binary chunks this is an even bigger problem, but loading binary chunks is also a bad idea for other reasons, and not in play here.)

(If you know that only C functions are forbidden, I guess some safety can be gained by checking whether functions are C or Lua.)

I would really want to whitelist a function immediately after it is created (by the `CLOSURE` bytecode operation) at which time we could check that the currently executing function is allowed to created whitelisted functions (e.g. if it is itself whitelisted, which would always be true if we can only execute whitelisted functions). But, I don't think there is a way to hook this event (at least, not without a lot of work and probably breaking some abstraction barriers like e.g. executing in a software VM at which point the problem is trivial anyway).

Note also that things like inner functions can't necessarily be whitelisted at the time the file is loaded because they may not even exist until runtime. (The prototype exists, but the prototype is not the Lua function object.) But, if there is no hook protection at runtime, there is nothing that would prevent these from executing at runtime since there is simply no protection at all about calling any kind of function (as discussed above).

This is also a problem with whitelisting inner functions from trusted APIs. For example, how do you make `string.gmatch` usable? Each time you execute this function, it returns a new C closure. You would have to hook and whitelist such functions. (And, now we should worry about running out of memory, so maybe using a weak table is prudent.)

I think sandboxing in this way seems dubious -- not only because of the difficulties above, but also because an attacker may cause trouble by a means other than calling a function like modifying some globally accessible table. (A natural way to fix this is to avoid giving access to sensitive data, but then we could also avoid giving access to sensitive functions...) I haven't read the book, so I don't really have an informed opinion on what kind of answer it is expecting and maybe I don't really understand what kind of protection it is trying to provide. In the context of an exercise, I wouldn't worry about it if you understand the issues.